# Cómo aplicar saltos en display flex

Tags: html, css, css3

Quiero saber como puedo aplicar un salto **br** con display flex, ya que display flex manda todo el contenido hacia la izquierda (como un float left) y quiero lograr que se puedan hacer espacios, digamos, una fila arriba y otra fila abajo, **ejemplo:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Celda 1 , 2 y 3 quiero que vayan arriba,
celda 4, 5 y 6 quiero que vayan abajo,**

```
<div id='caja-padre'>
<h1>celda 1</h1>   
<h1>celda 2</h1>  
<h1>celda 3</h1> 

<!-- aqui quiero lograr el salto -->
<h1>celda 4</h1> 
<h1>celda 5</h1> 
<h1>celda 6</h1> 
</div>

<style>
#caja-padre{
display: flex;
}
</style>
```

**Lo he logrado hacer así, pero no sé si es profesional la forma en cómo lo estoy haciendo**

```
<div id='caja-padre-edit'>

<div class='cajas-1-2-3'>contenido</div>

<div class='cajas-3-4-5'>contenido</div>

</div>

<style>
#caja-padre-edit{
position: relative;
overflow: hidden;
}
.cajas-1-2-3{
position: absolute;
top: 0; /* la caja irá arriba */
display: flex;
}
.cajas-4-5-6{
position: absolute;
bottom: 0; /* la caja irá abajo */
display: flex;
}
<style>
```

Answer (score 1):

La solución a tu problema es simple. 
Solo tienes que utlizar las herencias en css.

Tienes que meter contenedores `<div>contenido</div>` y ponerlos con `display:flex`.
También puedes utilizar `#caja-padre-edit div:first-child` para coger el primer elemento div dentro de `caja-padre-edit` en este caso para darle estilo o margenes.

Aquí te dejo tu código mas simplificado.

```html
<html>

<body>
<div id='caja-padre-edit'>
    <div>
        <h1>Celda 1</h1>
        <h1>Celda 2</h1>
        <h1>Celda 3</h1>
    </div>
    <div>
        <h1>Celda 4</h1>
        <h1>Celda 5</h1>
        <h1>Celda 6</h1>
    </div>
</div>
<style>
    #caja-padre-edit div {
        display: flex;
    }
</style>
</body>

</html>
```

También te recomiendo usar ficheros externos para insertar el css y facilitar su lectura.
Espero que te sirva.

Answer (score 1):

Esta es mi solución. No es necesario añadir nada más en el HTML. 
Le dices a la caja padre que puede flexionar (`flex-wrap:wrap;`). Ahora los elementos flex pueden aparecer colocados en varias líneas.
A los elementos `h1` les das `flex:1 1 30%`. Esto quiere decir que si es necesario pueden crecer ( **1** 1 30% ),  si es necesario pueden decrecer ( 1 **1** 30% ) y que tomen un ancho de mas o menos 30%.

Espero que sea útil

```css
*{margin:0;padding:0;}
#caja-padre{
display: flex;
flex-wrap:wrap;
}
h1{padding:.2em; 
  outline:1px solid;
  flex:1 1 30%
}
```

```html
<div id='caja-padre'>
<h1>celda 1</h1>   
<h1>celda 2</h1>  
<h1>celda 3</h1> 

<!-- aqui quiero lograr el salto -->
<h1>celda 4</h1> 
<h1>celda 5</h1> 
<h1>celda 6</h1> 
</div>
```